# table tfoot показывать на верху таблицы

Tags: html, css

Я читал в форуме о `<tfoot>` элементе, что он должен появиться после `<thead>` элемента. И все время его показывает внизу. Как сделать, чтобы его показать на верху таблицы.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: В этом то и дело, что порядок строго определен, дом строят начиная с фундамента, после уже идут стены и всё это дело накрывают крышей, а никак не наоборот!

Comment: Видно его не как нельзя поднять...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теги таблица на то и придуманы чтобы было логичное разделение блоков где: `<thead>` – это шапка таблицы, `<tbody>` – ее тело и `<tfoot>` – подвал, не иначе! Если уж вам это очень нужно, вы можете переопределить стили:

```css
tfoot {
  display: table-row-group;
  /*display: table-header-group; /* или так */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)))